# AJAX real-time detection issue

Tags: ajax

I have two files: 1.html and 1.php. There is a input in 1.html and a fire button. My goal is when I type something and fire the button to send this message to 1.php. In the mean time, 1.php is opened and received the message and display the message on the screen. Can I achieve this by AJAX? I tried to use AJAX but failed. I successfully get the callback function from jquery but there is nothing displayed on 1.php. In my html:

```
$(function(){
 $("#btn").click(function(){
  var myText = $("#text1").val();
  $.ajax({
   type: "post",
   url: "1.php",
   data: {"msg": myText},
   success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
  });
 });
});
```

In php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["msg"])){
echo $_POST["msg"]." from server!";
}
?>
```

If I keep 1.php opening. How can I echo something when I send something from client side (html file)? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't "open" `1.php`. You should only open `1.html`. php file is requested - using ajax - and it responds to this request (with echo) and it is the javascript that handles/displays that response...

also `console.log` will not display anything on the "screen" but only in the "console" so you need to open firebug console/chrome dev tools or whatever browser you're using..